# Is defuse/php-encryption suitable for use in network encryption?

Tags: php, encryption

I am currently managing two servers that have a shared secret key.

I would like to be able to send data between the servers in a manner that even if someone is listening in the middle, the data will be only read if someone has the secret key.
My requirements are:

- encryption
- authentication

But also:

- freshness: so that old encrypted data that has been intercepted in
  the past will not be accepted if transmitted now by someone else.

I was wondering if [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) is applicable to this scenario given that it provides encryption and authentication.
I also took a look at [libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php) but I want to stay away from PECL if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Purely for preventing MitM attacks, HTTPS/TLS is much more suitable. It removes the burden of managing encryption from the application layer and delegates it purely to the transport layer, which is where it's needed.

Comment: If your question is which one is "better" - `libsodium`. Why - because it's a joint effort between many experts, and it's designed to be modern, quick and secure. However, `defuse/php-encryption` uses `openssl` at its core, which is exposing strong crypto suite as well. Now, what you'll *most likely* achieve is implementation of `TLS` (exchange of the public key and then exchange of symmetric cipher) which brings you back to what deceze suggested - using `HTTPS` which does this for you. That means you'd have REST-ful interfaces between your servers. It's up to you to choose though.

Comment: @Mjh Heck, you can even have a TLS-protected socket connection if HTTP doesn't suit you... :)

Comment: How are those servers communicating? Through a socket that you establish in PHP service or is it HTTP? If you're dealing with sockets, then take a look at [zero.mq](http://zeromq.org/build:encryption). The first sentence at the link explains it better than I could. If this doesn't suit your need - ignore the comment :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use an *existing* cipher suite that can "blanket secure" the entire *connection* between the two parties.  Then, in any case, use **digital certificates** *(they can be self-signed ...)* to secure the connection.  (Do **not** use "shared secrets," *a.k.a.* "passwords.")

- **TLS** (the successor to SSL) is used by HTTPS secure web-sites. *(Be sure to use the current version of this protocol!)*
- **VPN** (as "OpenVPN" or "IPSec") provides "a secure router" between two subnets.  The advantage of this strategy is that the two parties don't have to do *anything* to obtain a secure, reliable connection:   it’s just *there.*
- **SSH** is also able to do "tunneling," but it's too-easy *(IMHO)* for data to wind up actually being passed insecurely, and it really doesn't provide identity-verification.

These cipher suites will provide you with three very important guarantees:

1. The data is not intelligible to any other party.
2. There is no "man in the middle."  The parties can *identify* exactly with whom they are communicating.
3. Messages received are known to be "exactly what the sender sent."
4. Nothing *in*-secure is passing "out of band" between the two parties.

... and yet, they operate completely "in the background," just as you routinely see TLS doing when you connect to a secure web-site. "It *is* secure, and 'it just works.'"  It is *very* important that your scheme be unobtrusive to authorized users.